# How can I remove the bolts holding down my utility sink?

Tags: removal, bolts

I have a utility sink that is sitting on 4 legs, the front two bolted to my cement floor and I want to remove it.

I'm not sure what kind of bolts these are. From looking at different kinds of bolts online they might be carriage or timber bolts.

[image: one of the bolts holding of one of the legs down]

How do I remove these? Is it as simple as having a pry bar and working it under to pull the bolt up out of the floor? That's what I briefly attempted to do, but I'm overly
 paranoid of doing damage and complicating things.

Answer (score 2):

Those look like concrete nails to me. Might have been hand-hammered in, but if it's somewhat recent, it was probably driven in with a powder-actuated system.

You don't usually try to pull these out. My advice is to cut/grind away the head. You can do this with a Dremel tool and an abrasive disk; it will take a while, but it's simple to do and easy to control.

Or, you can use an angle grinder. That will take away the head much more quickly, but it's a little harder to control. Make sure to use the screw-in handled if you do this.

Once the head it gone, remove the sink, and then either cut off the protruding fastener or just grind it away.